# Problems with table - extra column

Tags: tables, tabularx, booktabs, threeparttable

When I try to make my table - it won't create a fourth column. My preamble look like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[left=3.0cm,right=3.0cm,top=3.0cm,bottom=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteSettings}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteLabel}[1]{#1}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{threeparttable}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
%\renewcommand\tabcolsep{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\centering}p{0.15\textwidth}>{\raggedright}m{0.68\textwidth}
    p{\dimexpr0.17\textwidth-4\tabcolsep\relax}@{}}
\toprule
\mc{Name Number}& \mc{Hyp} & \mc{OneTwo} & \mc{ThreeFour}  \\
\midrule
1 & TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  & FALSIFY & SATISFY \\
2 & TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  & FALSIFY & SATISFY \\
3 & TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  & FALSIFY & SATISFY \\
4 & TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  & FALSIFY & SATISFY \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\vspace{-0.6em}
\end{document}
```

My figure look like this (I would like the column "ThreeFour" on the same line as "Name Number", "Hyp" and "OneTwo":

[image]

Comment: You are defining exatly 3 columns that add up to a width of three. I am not sure what you expect?

Comment: How can I change that?

Comment: Add an extra column specifier to the tabular preambule. Make sure to decrease the size of the other columns.

Comment: I just add "@{}" or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addiing an additional column is needed, each column has to be explicitely declared.

The spaces have been adjusted to the example, in your real tabular, you have to adjust them.

I deleted some of the stuff that i consider bad.

[image: afTabularExtraCol]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[left=3.0cm,right=3.0cm,top=3.0cm,bottom=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable}
\def\blindtext{
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam
    lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra
    sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper,
    felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a
    dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie
    ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in
}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}%[H]
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
        \begin{tabular}{
>{\centering}p{0.16\textwidth}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{0.45\textwidth}
>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.13\textwidth}
>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.13\textwidth}
}
            \toprule
            \centering Name Number& \centering Hyp & \centering OneTwo & \centering ThreeFour  \tabularnewline
            \midrule
            1 & \blindtext& FALSIFY & SATISFY \\\addlinespace
            2 & \blindtext& FALSIFY & SATISFY \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Depending on your real document, you might want to take a look at `tabularx`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[left=3.0cm,right=3.0cm,top=3.0cm,bottom=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\def\blindtext{
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam
    lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra
    sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper,
    felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a
    dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie
    ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in
}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}%[H]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c>{\raggedright}Xcc}
            \toprule
             Name Number&  Hyp &  OneTwo &  ThreeFour  \\
            \midrule
            1 & \blindtext& FALSIFY & SATISFY \\\addlinespace
            2 & \blindtext& FALSIFY & SATISFY \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: By the way, i recommend some basic reading up on typesetting tabular material.